# The operator $\operatorname{cl}_{\beta X}$ on cozero sets of a $F$-Space $X$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a Tychonoff space. Suppose that any cozero set of $\beta X$ is $C^*$-embedded. If $A$ and $B$ are cozero sets of $X$, how can I prove that
$$\operatorname{cl}_{\beta X} (A\cap B) = \operatorname{cl}_{\beta X} (A)\cap \operatorname{cl}_{\beta X} (B)?$$

---

If posible, I'd like to avoid any proof that uses ideals of $C(X)$.

Comment: Is it true that, for every $C^*$ embedded sets $W_0, W_1$ in $\beta X$, one has $\beta (W_0\cap W_1) = \beta W_0 \cap \beta W_1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Tychonoff space $X$, a subspace $S\subseteq X$ is $C^*$-embedded iff $\beta S = \operatorname{cl}_{\beta X} S$. Thus, assuming that any functionally open subspace $A\subseteq\beta X$ is $C^*$-embedded, given $W_0, W_1\in\operatorname{FO}(\beta X)$ one has 
$$\beta (W_0\cap W_1) =  \operatorname{cl}_{\beta X}(W_0\cap W_1) = \operatorname{cl}_{\beta X}(W_0)\cap \operatorname{cl}_{\beta X}(W_1) = \beta W_0\cap\beta W_1 .$$

Indeed, if $W_0,W_1\in \operatorname{FO}(\beta X)$, then $W_0\cap W_1\in \operatorname{FO}(\beta X)$; using the hypothesis that $\beta X$ is a $F$-space, any continuous function $f:W_0\cap W_1\to I$ can be extended to a continuous function $\overline{f}:\beta X\to I$ whose restriction $F = \overline{f}\restriction _{\operatorname{cl}_{\beta X}(W_0)\cap \operatorname{cl}_{\beta X}(W_1)}$ is also a continuous extension of $f$. Once $W_0\cap W_1$ is dense in the compact $\operatorname{cl}_{\beta X}(W_0)\cap \operatorname{cl}_{\beta X}(W_1)$,

$$\beta (W_0\cap W_1) = \operatorname{cl}_{\beta X}(W_0)\cap \operatorname{cl}_{\beta X}(W_1),$$

and, therefore,

$$\operatorname{cl}_{\beta X}(W_0\cap W_1) = \operatorname{cl}_{\beta X}(W_0)\cap \operatorname{cl}_{\beta X}(W_1).$$

Now, $\beta X$ is a normal space and, thus, any open subspace of $\beta X$ is functionally open. Therefore, given any functionally open $U_0, U_1$ subsets of $X$, there exists $W_0, W_1\in\operatorname{FO}(\beta X)$ such that $W_i\cap X = U_i$, for $i\in 2$. Thus, as $X$ is dense in $\beta X$, one has

$$\operatorname{cl}_{\beta X}(U_0\cap U_1) =\operatorname{cl}_{\beta X} (X\cap W_0\cap W_1) = \operatorname{cl}_{\beta X}(W_0\cap W_1) = \operatorname{cl}_{\beta X}(W_0)\cap \operatorname{cl}_{\beta X}(W_1) = $$
$$=\operatorname{cl}_{\beta X}(X\cap W_0)\cap \operatorname{cl}_{\beta X}(X\cap W_1) = \operatorname{cl}_{\beta X}(U_0)\cap \operatorname{cl}_{\beta X}(U_1),$$

as desired.

---

Obs.: I use *functionally open* set instead *cozero* set and $$\operatorname{FO}(X) = \{U\subseteq X: U\text{ is functionally open subset of }X\}$$